# Google Cloud Storage returning NoSuchKey for my public files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a public bucket here:
http://storage.googleapis.com/tripket1/

And all the files in this bucket have the ACL set to 'public-read'.  Yet when I try to view any of the files, such as:

http://storage.googleapis.com/tripket1/2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg

it returns a 'NoSuchKey' error.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

What could be causing this problem? These files were uploaded using the GCS client library for Java. Here's a code snipped from the uploader:

```
GcsFilename thumbGcsFilename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, thumb_filename);
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/" + photo_extension).acl("public-read").build();
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(thumbGcsFilename, options);
outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(newImageData));
outputChannel.close(); 
LOGGER.info("Wrote file");

String thumb_url_str = String.format("http://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s", bucketName, thumb_filename);
return thumb_url_str;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` character in your object names.

For example, you have the following object:

```
gs://tripket1/2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg
```

Since you have a literal percent sign in your object's name, it must be escaped as `%25` when URL encoded, so you can access the object with this URL:

http://storage.googleapis.com/tripket1/2013-05-25%252019.17.32_150.jpg

If you don't escape it, the `%20` in your object name gets turned into a space () when being decoded at the server side, and it doesn't find an object name with a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a publicly readable bucket, I used gsutil to look at its contents, and I see the object you're trying to read is called

2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg

rather than

06b78005-4ad8-43d6-8fc5-bab867b653af/2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg

Comment: Thanks for looking - I have modified the objects in there since posting so that original one no longer exists. Edited post to make this clear.

Since you see 2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg in there, shouldn't it be available at `storage.googleapis.com/tripket1/2013-05-25%2019.17.32_150.jpg`?

Comment: Jason - please see the comment from jterrace above - he's correct that you'll need to escape the %'s in your object names.