# Google Cloud Storage returning NoSuchKey for some public files without naming issues

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, storage

Any thoughts?  This is the file that returns "No Such Key".

https://storage.googleapis.com/building-agreement/Media/buildingagreement/layout/images/logo.png

I can open it from the browser from the GCS app, but not from my hosted static site

https://storage.googleapis.com/building-agreement/index.html

This is a similar issue, but different... I don't have % in my filename

[Google Cloud Storage returning NoSuchKey for my public files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845762/google-cloud-storage-returning-nosuchkey-for-my-public-files)

Answer (score 0):

Object names are case sensitive -- the object path says "Media" (capital M), but in the site's html it's spelled "media" (small m)